# Declaring a DOMAIN_HOME in setDomainEnv.sh and accessing it using cd

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I have declared the following in setDomainEnv.sh

```
DOMAIN_HOME="/opt/NI/Middleware/user_projects/domains/NI_domain"
export DOMAIN_HOME
```

but `echo $DOMAIN_HOME` is not showing the result  and `cd $DOMAIN_HOME/bin` is not taking to the path. setDomainEnv.sh is being from startWeblogic.sh.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are executing `setDomainEnv.sh` rather than sourcing it.  Assuiming `setDomainEnv.sh` is in the current directory, you want to run:

```
$ source setDomainEnv.sh
```

or

```
$ . setDomainEnv.sh
```

rather than

```
$ ./setDomainEnv.sh
```

or

```
$ bash setDomainEnv.sh
```

The `source` command reads in a file and executes its commands as if you typed them into the current shell yourself.  When executing a shell script, an entirely new process is forked and the commands are applied to that new process instead.